# Adding eSATA and USB 3.0 to my laptop - How much will this increase my laptop speed?

Tags: windows-vista, ssd, usb-3, esata

If I add USB 3.0 and eSATA to my laptop with an ExpressCard and connect an SSD to eSATA and another external hard to the USB 3.0 port will this speed up my laptop if now I am using an internal HDD and a USB 2.0 port? I want to increase my laptop speed!

Comment: This really depends on a number of factors regarding your existing system, the new SSD/HDD, your usage patterns, etc.  It's not possible to give a concrete "Your system will be *X* % faster".

Comment: All an external connection protocol will ever do is speed up connections to external devices. Things like external hard drives, USB flash drives and maybe other video/audio capture devices. So unless that is an issue to you, adding an ExpressCard won’t mean much.

Answer (score 2):

This would allow you to use drives with better specs which would perform better, as far as use of those drives is concerned. But your CPU is not going to be more powerful (consider looking into upgrading your CPU and RAM).

That said, and especially if you use programs such as DAWs or video editing software, having separate drives dedicated to read/write will reduce the load on your main drive by a noticeable amount.

Comment: Good first answer! This question is really all opinion-based — and a bit misinformed if you ask me — but your answer at least makes it all very clear on the pro/con side.

Answer (score 1):

USB 3.0 will not speed up your laptop, only the connection to the external hard drive.
If you want to speed up your laptop, look more at graphic settings (AMD or Intel), updating drivers and windows.

Comment: No i mean now i using HDD, if i use expresscard and add usb3.0 + esata to my laptop, and with that esata use SSD just for windows and use external hard with usb3.0 or my data.